# Experiencing Blinking/Flickering Effect When Changing Tabs in React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devextreme

When I switch between tabs in my application, I notice a blinking effect where the tab content appears to flicker before stabilizing. This issue is impacting the user experience, and I'd appreciate any guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix it.

I have a tabbed interface where each tab contains dynamic content.

I'm using React with devextreme Components for my frontend, and I'm rendering the tab content conditionally based on the selected tab.

I've tried various methods to mitigate this issue, but so far, none have provided a satisfactory solution.

If you need to see more of my code or specific components to provide guidance, please let me know, and I'd be happy to share.   [Here is a sample video of how blinking happening on Tabs.](https://youtu.be/51aMeIXg12E?si=bJh4SwEXoP0Mu7pB)
Here in the codesandbox code , i reproduced how my entire UI structure of tabs is :  [codesandbox.io](https://4cdz2s.csb.app/)

```
function renderTabConfig(e) {
   setTabName(e.editorOptions.name);
   const tabs = [];
      let selectedTabAttributesContent = null;
   let selectedTabCustomAttributesContent = null;
   Object.keys(e.editorOptions.value).map((item, index) => {
     let changeTabName = item === "Product" ? "Entitlement Line Item" : item;
     const isSelected = sapSelectedIndex === index;

     tabs.push(
       <Item title={changeTabName.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, " $1").trim()} key={item}>
         <div className="acc">
           <Accordion
             key={`attributes-accordion-${index}`}
             dataSource={[changeTabName.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, " $1").trim()]}
             className="field-bg"
             collapsible={true}
             repaintChangesOnly={true}
             itemRender={() => isSelected ? selectedTabAttributesContent : null}
             itemTitleRender={(data) => {
               return (
                 <div className="row">
                   <div className="col-3">{data}</div>
                 </div>
               );
             }}
           />
           <Accordion
             key={`custom-accordion-${item}`}
             dataSource={[changeTabName.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, " $1").trim() + " Custom Attribute"]}
             collapsible={true}
             className="field-bg"
             repaintChangesOnly={true}
             itemRender={() => isSelected ? selectedTabCustomAttributesContent : null}
             itemTitleRender={(data) => {
               return (
                 <div className="row">
                   <div className="col-9">{data}</div>
                   <div className="col-2">
                     <Button
                       className="btn btn_plus"
                       style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}
                       icon="plus"
                       onClick={() =>
                         handleTabAddcustomAttribute(
                           e.editorOptions.value,
                           e.editorOptions.name,
                           item
                         )
                       }
                     />
                   </div>
                 </div>
               );
             }}
           />
         </div>
       </Item>
     );
  //   console.log("isselected:",isSelected);
       if (isSelected) {
       if (!selectedTabAttributesContent) {
         selectedTabAttributesContent = handleTabAttributes(e.editorOptions.value, e.editorOptions.name, item);
       }
       if (!selectedTabCustomAttributesContent) {
         selectedTabCustomAttributesContent = handleTabCustomAttributes(e.editorOptions.value, e.editorOptions.name, item);
       }
     }
   });

   return (
     <div>
       <TabPanel
         className="child-tab-panel"
         selectedIndex={sapSelectedIndex}
         swipeEnabled={false}
         onOptionChanged={(args) =>
           onSelectionChanged(args, e.editorOptions.name, e.editorOptions)
         }
       >
       {tabs}
       </TabPanel>
      </div>
   );
 }
```

I tried using CSS changes and also tried with using Memo hooks to memoize the tabs and content on selection.

And also tried conditional rendering of tab content , But neither of the approach is worked fine. That flickering is continuing .